# Javascript can't get checkbox values to display string of information

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to build a simple order form in HTML, CSS and Javascript. I'm a beginner and am trying to have the input display a summary of the order as the user selects their order. I was able to make this work with radio buttons by doing the following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="crust"  onclick="crustOfPizza(this.value)" value="Original"> Original <br>
<input type="radio" name="crust"  onclick="crustOfPizza(this.value)" value="Garlic and Herb"> Garlic and Herb <br>
</form>

<p> Crust: </p> <output id="pizzaCrust"> </output> </br>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function crustOfPizza(crust) {
  document.getElementById("pizzaCrust").value = crust;  
}
```

However, I can't seem to get a similar result with checkboxes. I've tried the following:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="pizza-meat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    </form>

<p> Meat: </p> <output id="pizzaMeat"> </output>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function meatOnPizza() {
  var meat = document.forms[0];
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < meat.length; i++) {
    if (meat[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + meat[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("pizzaMeat").value = txt;
}
```

I appreciate any guidance anyone can offer!

Jessica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you simply forgot to insert a `<form>` opening tag before your checkboxes.

After inserting that (and the function declaration that is also missing from the JS code you posted), your code works fine:

**Edit:** I tried your updated code, and it works fine (see snippet below). The cause of your issue could be that this form **is not the first form** in your page, which causes `document.forms[0];` to return the wrong form.

Well, as you have assigned an ID to this form, why not use it directly instead of using `document.forms`? Then you could replace

```
var meat = document.forms[0];
```

By:

```
var meat = document.getElementById("pizza-meat");
```

```js
function meatOnPizza() {
  var meat = document.forms[0];
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < meat.length; i++) {
    if (meat[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + meat[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("pizzaMeat").value = txt;
}
```

```html
<form id="pizza-meat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    </form>

<p> Meat: </p> <output id="pizzaMeat"> </output>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to posting and it looks like the function and the form tags were cut off when posting this online. I have updated my examples. The code is still not working.